# Update an UIPageViewController content dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm looking for a solution to display content dynamically in an UIPageViewController.

My app is looking around for Bluetooth devices, and i show them as different pages of my UIPageViewController. User can do a few actions with all of these devices.

My aim is to add a new page each time my app is discovering a new device (or remove a page if a device isn't available any more).

It's my AppDelegate that is receiving notifications when a device is connected/disconnected.

Is it possible ? **Is there a right way to do it ?** I was thinking about calling an update method on my UIPageViewController, from my AppDelegate, and add/remove views from an Array, containing all the views. Thanks for your help !

Here is a sample of my DevicesPageViewController, as a DataSource AND Delegate of my UIPageViewController (note that i'm giving only methods that i have modified) :

Here is the .h

```
@interface DevicesPageViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

// Devices items, used for loading the data in
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *devices;

// All children view controllers : all the pages of my UIPageController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *childrenViewControllers;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

- (void) buildDataModelFromDevices;
- (void) updateView;

@end
```

Here is the .m :

```
@implementation DevicesPageViewController

- (id) init {
self = [super init];

// Init the pageViewController - This is the UIPageViewController
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphoneSTORYBOARD" bundle:nil];
self.pageViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

// Move the pageViewController where it belong
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// AT_appDelegate is a macro, getting the AppDelegate
if (AT_appDelegate.userDevices.count > 0) {
    [self updateView];
}

return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
return self;
}

#pragma mark - PageController DataSource

/**
 *  View controller to give before
 */
- (UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSUInteger index = ((DeviceContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) { return nil; }
index--;

return [self.childrenViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}

/**
 *  View controller to give after
 */
- (UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSUInteger index = ((DeviceContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == [self.childrenViewControllers count]) || (index == NSNotFound)) { return nil; }
index++;

return [self.childrenViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}

/**
 *  Build data model and init all children view controllers
 */
- (void) buildDataModelFromDevices {

int index = 0;
// For each device to load, create a viewController
for (Device *d in self.devices) {
    // Instantiate corresponding view controller
    DeviceContentViewController *deviceVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphoneSTORYBOARD" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"deviceContentVC"];

    // Load the device in it
    deviceVC.device = d;
    deviceVC.pageIndex = index;
    [deviceVC loadData];

    index++;
    [self.childrenViewControllers addObject:deviceVC];
}
}

- (void) updateView {
NSLog(@"[ DevicesPageViewController ] -- Updating view from devices...");

// Build the data
self.devices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:AT_appDelegate.userDevices];
[self buildDataModelFromDevices];

if (self.childrenViewControllers.count > 0) {
    // Get the first view controller
    NSArray *tmp_viewControllers = @[[self.childrenViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:tmp_viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:true completion:nil];
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Tell me your requirement...

Comment: I'm starting with iOS 6 devices, only iphone from now, what else can i add ?

Comment: Right, i've told it in my own answer. Thanks for adding duplicate flag :)